# Google Sheets function needed for concatenating strings

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

So I'm trying to create a function for work so I can't give exact details (which makes it hard) but essentially I'm trying to create a long URL.

On my google sheet, I have two sheets, Sheet1 & Filters.

On Sheet1 there are 7 columns.
1st column can be left empty depending on if I need something from Filters which I will get into later.
2nd -6th column I enter different things and are required. It concatenates everything key terms and whatever is added into those cells. These columns cannot be changed as they are the minimum requirement for this excel sheet to work.
7th column spits out the URL I need. I have a IF function to say if 1st column is empty, then concatenate key terms and values in 2nd to 6th column. If 1st column has a value, I have a v lookup to pull an exact match from Sheet B, then concatenate key terms and values in 2nd to 6th column.

On Filters I have parts of a URL that are needed if there is a value in the 1st column in Sheet1.
1st column contains the value entered into the 1st column on Sheet1.
2nd column shows the part of the URL that the 7th column from Sheet1 will spit out if 1st column from Filters is entered.

The part of the URL shown in the 2nd column of Filters is comprised of two things. The first part of it is what category the value in 1st column is (product, gender, age, language, etc), and the second part is the actual value. I will be calling this (A) and (B) respectively. These are separated by an & sign.

My goal is to be able to combine multiple Filters 1st column values together (ex: Mens, Womens, Water etc), and connect them to the concatenated URL in Sheet1.

The 3 problems I have that need to be fixed are:
When multiple Filters 1st column values are combined together, the URL is broken into category then actual value. For example if I want green & plants, the URL is category (in this case, color and product) then green&plants. So the resulting URL is something like color1&product2&1=green&2=plants . It also adds a number after the category as shown in the URL on the left.
When I have multiple values that are of the same category, it is separated by a %7C. For example if I want green & blue, the URL is color&green%7Cblue .
The other issue is, on Sheet1 1st column, I want to be able to add multiple values and pull multiple values from Filters with the above two problems solved, in 1 cell. So two or more values in a cell. If this isn't possible I guess I can add more filters to the left of the URL, but I need to be able to add about 15 filters.

The end goal is to create a URL with multiple Filters. Example, (?prefn1=WaterResistance&prefn2=genderGroup&prefn3=productClass&prefv1=Waterproof&prefv2=Men%27s&prefv3=Jackets&icp=XY&id=YD&ica=GA&pr=KK&cr=JE). In this example, after 'Jackets&' the rest of the URL is concatenated from Sheet1, and this part I already have at work, and is part of the forumla I have on Sheet1 column G. I am currently able to create a URL with 1 filter but that's about it.

This is a very confusing question and I would like to get this solved if possible!

Comment: it would help if you could perhaps share a copy of the spreadsheet with dummy data. From what I've understood so far, this should easily be possible.

Comment: If you don't use Excel, please don't tag with Excel. The two are really different. Removing Excel tag.

Comment: Hi, this is a sample spreadsheet. Thanks! https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QFzdAA4-1d-JhSC69h6LLILPuN6x-aejAUqS2jaMNYA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(IF((B2:B<>"")*(C2:C<>"")*(D2:D<>"")*(E2:E<>"")*(F2:F<>""),
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, Filters!A2:B, 2, 0))&
 "icp="&B2:B&"&id="&C2:C&"&ica="&D2:D&"&pr="&E2:E&"&cr="&F2:F, ), " ", "%7C"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Hi, thank you for the function. If I were to try and add 2 or more filters, how would I go about that? Also I'm not able to copy the formula. When I do, it deletes all the other formulas

Comment: @nikeman you can add as many as you like but it depends if they are mandatory or choosable. copy where? why? how? this is ArrayFormula which means its auto-populated downwards as needed meaning you need to have this in the upper cell only (thats row 2 for your scenario) - check the sheet you provided as sample sheet

Comment: Sorry I should’ve clarified further, but I meant adding 2 or more filters into the same row. As in, can I put multiple filters into column A, so that it gives me a URL with multiple filters applied? They are not mandatory, but need to follow the prefn1, prefn2 that I mention in the third sheet.

Comment: I see... yes you can but not sure how you wish to join/assemble it. for example Mens and Water... like this: `?prefn1=genderGroup&prefv1=Men%27s&prefn1=activity&prefv1=Water&icp=XY&id=YD&ica=GA&pr=KK&cr=JE` ??

Comment: @nikeman here is an example with up to 3 filters: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSSct.png

Comment: It's a bit more complicated with multiple filters. If I were to use waterproof, men and jackets it would be ?prefn1=WaterResistance&prefn2=genderGroup&prefn3=productClass&prefv1=Waterproof&prefv2=Men&prefv3=Jackets&icp=XY&id=YD&ica=GA&pr=KK&cr=JE

Comment: With multiple filters of the same type would be ?prefn1=genderGroup&prefv1=Men%7CWomen&icp=XY&id=YD&ica=GA&pr=KK&cr=JE . 

   where men and women are separated by a %7C

Comment: is this possible?